# Is there a way for me to check if a song exists on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can i see if a song exists on the phone? This is for when i'm loading up the app, so i can see if they've removed the song or not.

Comment: If ur question doesnt deal with the editor xcode don't tag it xcode. It doesnt matter for these kinds of questions if u use xcode or some other IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you wanting to check this based on a song that they've selected before whilst your app is running or based on song title and artist?

If it's based on a media item that they've selected from their iPod library in the past whilst using your app then you can identify a song based on it's `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID` and do an `MPMediaQuery` the next time you load and do a check:

```
//Use the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID to find the song  
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:savedPersistenID forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID]; 
MPMediaQuery *songQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init]; 
[songQuery addFilterPredicate: predicate]; 
if (songQuery.items.count > 0) {
    //song exists  
}
```

Note: I haven't actually run this code, just looked at the documentation and some example pieces of code that I found. Hopefully it's along the lines of what you're wanting, but I haven't actually tested it or used the code myself.

Also, having looked into the `MPMediaItem` Documentation it would seem that you could do a search based off artist and title etc. Please look at the `MPMediaItem` class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008211-CH1-SW22), for further details on what you can search with. But if you want to search based on an exact song that has been selected in the past then it would be more reliable basing it off the `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID`.